# What does ' com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Serializing Arrays is not supported, please use Lists instead' mean?

Tags: java, android, firebase

the main

```
public class SignupCarrier extends AppCompatActivity {

Button upProfile, upIDPhoto, upCriminalRecord, buttonSigningUp;
private Uri mProfilePic, mIdPhoto,mCriminalRecord;

FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    List<String> picturesUrls = new ArrayList<String>();



private StorageReference mStorageRef;
private StorageTask mUploadTask;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_PROFILE = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID = 1;
    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup_carrier);
        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        upProfile = (Button) findViewById(R.id.profilePic);
        upIDPhoto = (Button) findViewById(R.id.idphotoPic);
        upCriminalRecord = (Button) findViewById(R.id.criminalRecord);
        buttonSigningUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSigningUp);
        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("carriersPictures");

        upProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser(mProfilePic);
            }
        });
        upIDPhoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser(mIdPhoto);
            }
        });
        upCriminalRecord.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser(mCriminalRecord);
            }
        });

        buttonSigningUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                uploadFile(mProfilePic,"profilePicture");
                uploadFile(mIdPhoto,"idPicture");
                uploadFile(mCriminalRecord,"criminalRecordPicture");
                picturesUrls.toArray(pictureUrls);


                mFirebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            final CarrierUser carrierUser = new CarrierUser(

                                    picturesUrls

                            );
                            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("User")
                                    .child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(carrierUser).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(SignupCarrier.this,"Your request has been sent for approval", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                        openLogin();

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });



            }
        });

 private  String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }
    private void uploadFile(Uri path,String forWho) {

        if(path != null) {

            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(editemail.getText().toString()+"-"+forWho+"-"+System.currentTimeMillis()+getFileExtension(path));
            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(path)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                          picturesUrls.add(taskSnapshot.getUploadSessionUri().toString());
                        }
                    })
            .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(SignupCarrier.this, e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

    }
    private void openFileChooser( Uri urltoPhoto) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        if (urltoPhoto == mProfilePic) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_PROFILE);
        } else if (urltoPhoto == mIdPhoto) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID);
        } else if (urltoPhoto == mCriminalRecord) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR);
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_PROFILE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mProfilePic = data.getData();


        }
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_ID && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mIdPhoto = data.getData();


        }
        if(requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST_CR && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
        {
            mCriminalRecord = data.getData();


        }
    }
```

I get that error and only uploads 2 of 3 files to storage and in the database the user is missing. 
Before using the array I tried with a List but same error, maybe I was mistypping or I don't know.
Can you please help me out to understand this error and how to fix it?

UPDATE! Now It's working, but the field picturesURl are missing from database.
 new Object

```
public class CarrierUser {
    public List<String> picturesUrls;
public CarrierUser() {
}

public CarrierUser(List<String> picturesUrls) {
this.picturesUrls = picturesUrls;
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an array:

```
String[] pictureUrls = new String[picturesUrls.size()];
```

This is a list:

```
List<String> picturesUrls = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The error message says you can't serialize arrays - so try changing the array to a list in the object you want to serialize (the CarrierUser).

Comment: Now all files are uploaded, but in my database field picturesUrls is still missing. I edited the question